# What is the importance of rock salt (sendha namak) in fasting?

Tags: practice, food, ayurveda, fasting

Rock salt is given special preference in fasting, while there are several parts of India where no form of salt is consumed during fasts. What is its importance and why it is not followed everywhere in India?

Rock Salt is known as Sendha Namak in Hindi.

Comment: Namaste 1) There is no real significance of rock salt during fasting
2) Technically, rock has more minerals than other forms of sea salt
3) Probably it is something of a practice started by some ayurvedic reasons
4) Else, it has no signficant relevance for there is none described in anyhwere in hindu scriptures

Comment: It is naturally processed and tastes less salty and he nice used during fasting

Comment: @Annonymous Please write your points as an answer with sources.

Comment: @BhavinPatel, your reference says "*Some studies have also shown that it does not increase blood pressure, unlike common marine salt.*", without any references to what "some studies" means. This is unsubstantiated nonsense.  All rock salt was originally marine salt. Any differences in trace elements are insignificant when compared with the sodium chloride that makes up the vast majority of the salt. Salt from either source has an identical effect on blood pressure.

Comment: Rock salt is the only type of salt allowed for consumption according to orthodoxy. Till to this day, priests of Jagannath Temple in Puridhama refuse to allow usage of any salt in the preparation of Mahaprasada apart from rock-salt.

Comment: Sea salt contains dead elements, and was not considered pure. At least that's what i have heard. Many blamed India's high construction of rock salt to iodine deficiency.